# How to pass mutiple bytearray image in .net soap webservice

Tags: android, .net, soap-client, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

[image]

I'm trying to send byte array image in ArrayList its giving error as Cannot serialize. please help me to code this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you youe `KvmSerilizer` you can define the Property like this to create an array:

```
info.setName("ProjectImage");
info.setType(PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS);
elementType.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
elementType.setName("base64Binary");
elementType.setNamespace(Constants.NAMESPACE);
info.setElementType(elementType);
```

But I think you need vector instead of ArrayList, otherwise the serelizer will not work.

Your attribute should be `private Vector<byte[]>`.

In addition you need a marshaler that transform your `byte[]` to base64 string:

```
public class MarshalBase64 implements Marshal {

    @Override
    public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser parser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo expected) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        String str = parser.nextText();

        byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(str, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return  decoded;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer writer, Object instance) throws IOException {
        byte[] data = (byte[]) instance;
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        writer.text(encoded);
    }

    @Override
    public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope) {
        envelope.addMapping("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "base64Binary", byte[].class, this);
    }
}
```